# How to further pretrain a bert model using our custom data and increase the vocab size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pre-trained-model, bert-language-model

I am trying to further pretrain the bert-base model using the custom data. The steps I'm following are as follows:

1. Generate list of words from the custom data and add these words to the existing bert-base vocab file. The vocab size has been increased from `35022` to `35880`.
2. I created the input data using **create_pretraining_data.py** from [the bert official github page](https://github.com/google-research/bert).
3. Doing the pretrain using **run_pretraining.py** but facing the mismatch error:

> ValueError: Shape of variable bert/embeddings/word_embeddings:0
> ((35880, 128)) doesn't match with shape of tensor
> bert/embeddings/word_embeddings ([30522, 128]) from checkpoint reader.

**Note:** I changed the `bert_config` file with lastest `vocab_size` as `35880`.

Please help me to understand the error and what changes should be made, so that I can pretrain with the custom vocab file.

Comment: Can you add some code? Doing `config=BertConfig(vocab_size=35880)` and then `model=Bert.from_pretrained("name-here", config=config)` should work.

Comment: I am using the existing code from Bert github repository and it doesnot have any specific line like BertConfig as such, could you please share in terms of bert code. https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-training-with-bert

Answer (score 2):

You can further pretrain a BERT model with your own data with run_mlm.py at: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/pytorch/language-modeling.

Also look at this: https://github.com/allenai/dont-stop-pretraining and the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.10964.pdf for related ideas and terminology: domain-adaptive pertaining and task-adaptive
pretraining.